# Safety of "Safe" Solvents

Tags: ventilation, paint-removal

I put off stripping the paint of my interior trim until the winter, since there were so many more pleasant outdoor tasks during the warmer months. Now that it's time to fish or cut bait, I'm thinking about ventilation.

The paint I am trying to remove seems to be latex, just a coat or two, and not terribly ancient. (I'm very confident it's not lead-based). I started out (over the summer) using denatured alcohol as a stripper, but it was pretty slow going, lots of scraping, so I recently picked up some multi strip, which has dibasic esters, ethoxyproprionate, and benzyl alcohol as active ingredients. Not as dangerous as methylene chloride, but not exactly non-toxic either.

If I don't want to open my windows in January in Chicago, should I just put this project off until spring? Or will I be fine with the natural ventilation of my forced air system? The effected area will be in just two rooms--living room and dining room.

Comment: stripper fumes aren't really "bad" for you long-term in a toxicological sense, but they can cause headaches or dizzyness. Can you paint before you go shopping or something so that you miss the worst concentrations?

Comment: Thanks--I do gather that for these kind of inhalants to cause damage you have to have a lot of long term exposure. I guess I'm trying to understand better where the lines are.

Comment: About anything sold to consumers can be safely used by fools who can follow directions. The stuff that we need to worry about these days (as in not the 60s anymore) takes training and licensing and is meant for pros. Run the bathroom and kitchen exhaust to help eliminate odor faster.

Comment: **Why** are you stripping off the paint? The wood underneath is likely to be "paint grade", i.e. not attractive for staining/varnishing, with finger-joints, filled knots, etc. If you are just repainting you *don't need* to strip the existing paint in most circumstances...

Comment: This is old trim, red oak, in a 100-year old house. It shows nice.

Comment: @ChristopherSchoen  Sweet!  I can see why you want to strip it and probably clear coat it afterwards.   Again, I stand by my recommendation of Cistriustrip.  Try it, if you don't like it, just go with something else.   I've had good luck with it on parts that I thought it couldn't touch, but it did the job.

Comment: you really don't want your forced air system circulating the fumes round the whole house. if you don't want cold air coming in through the window set up some sort of fan so that air only goes out the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to just remove latex paint, it might be better to try something more targeted at latex paint.  That usually means less chemicals in the cocktail involved.

There's a product called Krud Kutter, Latex Pain Remover that contains Acetone, and something called Dipropylene Glycol n-Propyl Ether.  Googling the latter indicates there's some decent evidence from valid sources like NIH that this stuff is relatively low toxicity.

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15705495/

In general, I'd choose a more targeted stripper with the least toxic substances you can find than a general one that'll take off everything.

It seems strippers are getting quite a bit less toxic than "the bad old days" of methylene chloride.  I'd still be cautious of this stuff, since stripppers are still likely the nastiest chemicals most consumers experience.

There's other alternatives out their, like infra-red heaters (different from a heat gun).  Since you say there's no lead, this may present a completely non-toxic way to strip the latex.  I haven't used them myself, but I do recall a friend having good luck with them.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a paint stripper recommendation, but this might come in handy:

[image]

Due to COVID they're a little bit more expensive, but still available. 3M 7502 mask is comfortable and easy to breathe through. What you need here is "Organic Vapor Cartridge" like 3M 6001 or similar. It is very effective at filtering out solvents and makes paint stripping, or even painting with smelly paint, a much less "intoxicating" experience.

You'll still need to ventilate the room once you're done, but you won't need to keep the windows open during the whole job.

Comment: Thanks--it's hard to find info on whether these filter out alcohols and esters, but maybe that's because these aren't the compounds people are really worried about.

Comment: Don't know about alcohol, but it works very well with solvents, and also for plumbing... it blocks the nasty smell that comes out of drain pipes lol

Answer (score -1):

I would rather have posted this as a comment, but pics don't work in comments so I'm posting this as an answer.   Also while product recommendations are frowned upon here, I'll bend the rules a bit and post this.  I've had great luck with this product. It's pretty non-toxic, actually smells like oranges! And works pretty well. You have to have patience, it's not nearly as fast as a harsh chemical stripper and you may have to apply twice so as not to let it dry out. You'll still want to wear gloves and follow labelled directions,   But it's pretty environmentally friendly, easy to wash brushes and even the work product in plain water.

[image: Citristrip]

Comment: Should mention that sticking saran wrap on the wet goop keeps it from drying out and can reduce the number of applications, which reduces fumes, effort, and costs.

Comment: Thanks -- I know the chemical makeup of Citris Strip is slightly different, but I notice that the Safety Data Sheet for Citris Strip recommends opening all windows when using it, so my same question would apply.

Comment: I've used it in my shop frequently with no windows or doors open. I think the Safety Data Sheet is largely lawyer driven, trying to avoid any potential liability.  I also think the chemical makeup of it is quite different than other strippers.  I've used a product called "Zip Strip" long ago, it worked great, but it was nasty stuff.  So I'm going to stand by my original recommendation.   I find it to be an environmentally friendly product with no harsh fumes.

Comment: @dandavis  That it's a great suggestion. I'm not sure if Citris Strip would dissolve the plastic, but worth a try.

Comment: It comes in a plasic container so it's safe with at-least some plastics

Comment: which drain cleaner dissolves seran wrap?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact do you find drain cleaner is good at removing paint?

Comment: @Jasen  LOL at your comment, good point!  But there are lots of types of plastic so who knows for sure, but you're probably right.

Comment: My point was simply that something coming in plastic tells you very little about how strong/weak/able to dissolve other plastic/etc. a chemical is. Drain cleaner to strip paint? Would probably work, but would take the wood with it :-)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   NP, guy. Agreed. My only point was plastic wrap (IE: Saran wrap) seemed pretty wimpy to stand up to a stripper, but I was probably wrong!  LOL....I shouldn't post until I've had at least 2 cups of coffee first!